# Error with DynamodB Batchget

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I'm currently trying to make AWS.dynamodB.document().batchGet work.
My params :

```
{  
    "RequestItems":{  
        "Places":{  
            "Keys":[  
                {  
                    "id":"ChIJ-cJN7tlx5kcRG3I5nIqlJvM"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "ReturnConsumedCapacity":"TOTAL"
}
```

Right now i'm getting this error:

```
  {
    "errorMessage": "Reflect is not defined",
    "errorType": "ReferenceError",
    "stackTrace": [
        "Module._compile (module.js:409:26)",
        "Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)",
        "Module.load (module.js:343:32)",
        "Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)",
        "Module.require (module.js:353:17)",
        "require (internal/module.js:12:17)"
    ]
}
```

When i use  AWS.dynamodB.batchGetItem with the same params it' work but 
i got an insane JSON

Comment: I am wondering whether the answer was helpful to resolve the issue?

Comment: yes thank , it worked !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My table has both hash and sort key. The below params is working for me.

```
var params = {
    "RequestItems" : {
        "Movies" : {
            "Keys" : [ {
                "yearkey" : {N : "2016"},
                "title" : {S : "The Big New Movie 1"}
            } ]
        }
    },
    "ReturnConsumedCapacity" : "TOTAL"
};

dynamodb.batchGetItem(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to read item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err,
                null, 2));
    } else {
        console.log("GetItem succeeded:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
    }
});
```

**Please try the below for your scenario.**

```
var params = {
        "RequestItems" : {
            "Places" : {
                "Keys" : [ {
                    "id" : {S : "ChIJ-cJN7tlx5kcRG3I5nIqlJvM"}                  
                } ]
            }
        },
        "ReturnConsumedCapacity" : "TOTAL"
    };
```